# Retain cell comments when emailing Excel table (using RangeToHTML)

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I'm using an adjusted version Ron de Bruin's well known 'rangetoHTML' to email an Excel range using Outlook (as found here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm). While this works fine, some of the cells have comments which logically do not get carried over into outlook.

I thought it might be possible to add the comments as tooltips adding in a bit of CSS (as found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp), but am not sure if a) Outlook supports tooltip in the HTML email (I've seen conflicting messages), and b) if it DOES, how to implement it in the html spit out by publishobjects

Relevant bit to spit out the HTM, but am confused as to how to go about including tooltips.

```
   With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
       HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
      .Publish (True)
  End With
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.  If it looks promising, I will complete it, although probably not until the weekend.

I have output a range using PublishObjects and have then amended the output file to add a tool tip as you require.  With Microsoft Edge, the amended file displayed correctly and the tip appeared when I hovered over the relevant cell.  I have not tried this with Outlook but I assume Outlook uses the same display engine as Edge so it should work with Outlook.  This will need to be tested before doing much more work.

Ron de Bruin has provided an excellent routine that prepare almost any range for PublishObjects, call PublishObjects, get the file it creates and return it as a string ready to become the Html body of an email.

As far as I can tell, there is no way of getting PublishObjects to add comments to the output in the way you require.  You will have to add the necessary code.

With approach 1, you need new code in function `RangeToHtml` between “get the file it creates” and “return it as a string”.  That is, you let PublishObjects do its thing and then you amend its output before returning that output to the caller.

A lot of the code in function `RangeToHtml` allows for the range being non-contiguous which, I assume, PublishObjects does not handle.  If you have a simple range, it would be easier to create a new `RangeToHtml` that handles simple ranges plus your requirement.  This would be approach 2.

Would approach 1 or approach 2 better meet your requirements.

The Html file created by PublishObjects contains a single table.  There is nothing in the table to indicate which table cell comes from which Excel range cell.  If row 2, column 5, of the range has a comment, you will have to count down the s and then the s to find the corresponding table cell.  That table cell will have to be amended.  If the existing cell value is Xxxx and the comment is Yyyy, you will need to replace Xxxx with:

```
<div class="tooltip">Xxxx<span class=tooltiptext>Yyyy</span></div>
```

Does this sound interesting?

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for your reply! I was thinking about doing it the same way; loop through the HTML table and add the tooltip code for any value that has a comment. Does the HTML table intrinsically holds the same pattern as the Excel sheet in terms of rows/columns? Is row 1 of my range in excel the also row 1 in the HTML table - I understand from you that it is the same, which makes life easier. I thought about building the HTML table from a range from scratch as well, but I like using publishobjects as it maintains formatting automatically, so I guess approach #1 is preferred.

Comment: @JasperD  The Html table certainly appears to match the Excel range.  Near the bottom of `RangeToHtml` there is `Kill TempFile`.  Delete that statement and the temporary file will not be deleted so you can examine it as I did.  I can see no extra rows or columns not can I imagine why there would be.

Comment: @JasperD My approach 2 would also use PublishObjects. `RangeToHtml` creates a temporary workbook, copies the range to Sheet(1) and then calls PublishObjects to output Sheet(1).  You can output the range from its original worksheet if it is a simple range.  My approach 2 would leave all that complicated stuff out.

Comment: It is possible to convert an Excel range to Html using VBA and copy all the formatting but it takes much longer than PublishObjects.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of all that - I'll give it a try; and, you never know with HTML, it's sometimes counter intuitive, and I'm not good at writing that at all, so that's why I had my doubts. I tried to skip creating a new workbook etc, but for some reason publishobjects doesn't seem to publish if there are multiple sheets in the workbook, hence the need to create a single-sheet workbook, it seems. Do I need to add the css bit by the way or is adding the line you put in your answer sufficient?

Comment: @JasperD If you visit https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip you will see a complete Html file. At the top is a style element. I added the contents of that style element to the top of PublishObjects' style element. I then amended some td element contents as I described in my answer.  Note, the style elements in that example position the tip badly. You will need to adjust the css to give a better appearance. I was interesting to checking it was possiblerather than getting the best possible appearance.

Comment: Thanks - will give it a try and will revert back if I can't figure it out - and suggestions on how to change the position? (I know virtually nothing about CSS/HTML)

Comment: It doesn't work in Outlook (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/any-hover/) - the title element doesn't work either, so I am going to assume that it won't be possible.